# Cannot Correctly Parse Json Using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I cannot figure out why my json Parsing is not working. Here is the Api I am working with. Also the link for the full json output http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?zip=85008&amode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&APPID=3c6fee6e3e8b5764212701d9535a36d5

```
{  
"city": {  
        "id": 5308655,  
        "name": "Phoenix",  
        "coord": {  
            "lon": -112.074043,  
            "lat": 33.44838  
        },  
        "country": "US",  
        "population": 0  
    },  
    "cod": "200",  
    "message": 0.014,  
    "cnt": 7,  
    "list": [  
        {  
            "dt": 1454871600,  
            "temp": {  
                "day": 10.46,  
                "min": 10.46,  
                "max": 10.46,  
                "night": 10.46,  
                "eve": 10.46,  
                "morn": 10.46  
            },  
            "pressure": 977.01,  
            "humidity": 32,  
            "weather": [  
                {  
                    "id": 800,  
                    "main": "Clear",  
                    "description": "sky is clear",  
                    "icon": "01n"  
                }  
            ],  
            "speed": 4.1,  
            "deg": 45,  
            "clouds": 0  
        },  
        {  
            "dt": 1454958000,    
            "temp": {  
                "day": 16.88,  
                "min": 3.31,  
                "max": 24.29,  
                "night": 11.29,  
                "eve": 23.78,  
                "morn": 4.31  
            },  
            "pressure": 979.15,  
            "humidity": 30,  
            "weather": [  
                {  
                    "id": 800,  
                    "main": "Clear",  
                    "description": "sky is clear",  
                    "icon": "01d"  
                }  
            ],  
            "speed": 2.41,  
            "deg": 52,  
            "clouds": 0  
        },
```

I am trying to get the min and max temps from each day. Here is my code. The exception thrown is Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 190. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_list);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new ArrayList<List1>());

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    WeatherAPI weatherAPI = retrofit.create(WeatherAPI.class);

    Call<Weather> call = weatherAPI.loadWeather("85008", "json", "metric", "7", "3c6fee6e3e8b5764212701d9535a36d5");
    call.enqueue(this);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Weather> call, Response<Weather> response) {
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    arrayAdapter.addAll(response.body().list);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Weather> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.v(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), t.getLocalizedMessage());
}


public interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET("/data/2.5/forecast/daily")
    Call<Weather> loadWeather(
            @Query("zip")String zip,
            @Query("amode")String amode,
            @Query("units")String units,
            @Query("cnt")String cnt,
            @Query("APPID")String APIKey);
}



public class Weather{
    public List<List1> list;
}


public class List1{
    double dt;
    public HashMap<String, Temps> temp;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "Min and High ";

        for(Map.Entry<String,Temps> temps:temp.entrySet()){
            output += temps.getKey() + " = " + temps.getValue().min;
        }
        return output;


    }
}


public class Temps{
    double min;
    double max;

}
```

Comment: Can you please share WeatherAPI?

Comment: i think it's not right to represent Temp as hash in list1 class, it should be a single object `Temps temp;` because in json it's 1 `temp` per list item

Comment: That was it! Thank you Yazan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp` is not a an array, its class object.

One thing you should know retrofit will not support direct hash map retrieve(Pojo approach).

`public HashMap<String, Temps> temp;` -- This approach is wrong.

`public Temps temp;` -- This is correct.

If you want to store your response in `HashMap`, there is some other workaround, You should look that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yazan the answer is

```
public class Weather{
    public List<List1> list;
}


public class List1{
    double dt;
    public Temps temp;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "List1{" +
                "temp min = " + temp.min + " temp max " + temp.max + " dt = "+ dt+
                '}';
    }
}


public class Temps{
    double min;
    double max;
}
```

}

Where Temps is not displayed by a hashmap but rather a single object. I hope this helps someone I know it helped me.